# QR code scanning goes wrong with the python code

Tags: python, qr-code

I have a python script which is intended to scan and decode the QR codes

```
import string
from evdev import InputDevice
from select import select

keys = "X^1234567890XXXXqwertzuiopXXXXasdfghjklXXXXXyxcvbnmXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
dev = InputDevice('/dev/input/by-id/usb-Manufacturer_Barcode_Reader-event-kbd')

while True:
   r,w,x = select([dev], [], [])
   for event in dev.read():
        if event.type==1 and event.value==1:
                print( keys[ event.code ] )
```

If I scan the Qr code with this set of keys, I dont get any special characters like `&=:\\` as they are not available in `keys` but if I change the that line as

`keys = "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm[];,./{}:X^!@#$%^&*()_+-=1234567890`

the decoded string get more worse. So Is there any special instruction to to change it ?
The actual string should be like `name=random&&age=23&&gender=male`

but it appears as `namexrandomxxagex2x3xxgenderxmale`

and with my changes it becomes more dirty. How should I change the keys line to get correct string.

Answer (score 0):

Got the error, there is a sequence for all the keys, if we edit it in random manner not according to keyboard layout. We get weird results, to avoid that store key sequence according to key pattern on keyboard.